# gRPC unable to create connection to server (Go) from client (Python)

Tags: grpc, rpc

I have this Python code that is supposed to use a certificate and connect to a server via the server's IP address (no FQDN available) but I get an error every time I try it:

```
ssl_transport_security.cc:222]                 LOOP - TLS client process_change_ciph  - !!!!!!
ssl_transport_security.cc:222]                 LOOP - TLS client read_server_finishe  - !!!!!!
ssl_transport_security.cc:222]                 LOOP - TLS client finish_client_hands  - !!!!!!
ssl_transport_security.cc:222]                 LOOP -                TLS client done  - !!!!!!
ssl_transport_security.cc:222]       HANDSHAKE DONE -                TLS client done  - !!!!!!
security_handshaker.cc:184] Security handshake failed: {"created":"@1582052112.923538253","description":"Peer name 172.18.0.14 is not in peer certificate","file":"src/core/lib/security/security_connector/ssl/ssl_security_connector.cc","file_line":55}
subchannel.cc:1003]         Connect failed: {"created":"@1582052112.923538253","description":"Peer name 172.18.0.14 is not in peer certificate","file":"src/core/lib/security/security_connector/ssl/ssl_security_connector.cc","file_line":55}
subchannel.cc:940]          Subchannel 0x55ad70542020: Retry immediately
subchannel.cc:967]          Failed to connect to channel, retrying
```

From what I understand this could be due to me connecting to an ip address and not a FQDN but these are servers and I only have access to IP addresses. Any idea how to overcome this?

Python code used:

```
def get_secure_channel(host, port):
    if os.environ.get('https_proxy'):
        del os.environ['https_proxy']
    if os.environ.get('http_proxy'):
        del os.environ['http_proxy']

    with open(os.path.join(settings.DJANGO_ROOT, '../grpc_proto/cert/server.crt'), 'rb') as f:
        cert = f.read()

    credentials = grpc.ssl_channel_credentials(root_certificates=cert)
    return grpc.secure_channel('{}:{}'.format(host, port), credentials)

def reset_client(channel, ip_address):
    stub = dnsadblock_pb2_grpc.DnsadblockServiceStub(channel)
    return stub.ResetClient(dnsadblock_pb2.ResetClientRequest(ipAddress=ip_address))

channel = get_secure_channel(c.server.hostname, settings.GRPC_PORT)
rpc.reset_client(channel, c.ip_address)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/what-is-common-name/

In this case, the endpoint you are connecting are not matching the description of peer's certificate. Hence, the connection was rejected. You could either try to use one of the CN in your certificate to connect to the server. Or adding the endpoint to your certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I was integrating a go grpc server and a Python client. To make it work I did the following.

When creating the server.csr file using this line

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -key certs/server.key -out certs/server.csr -config certs/certificate.conf
```

The certs/certificate.conf looked likes this:

```
[req]
default_bits = 4096
prompt = no
default_md = sha256
req_extensions = req_ext
distinguished_name = dn
[dn]
C = AU
ST = VIC
O = OCOM Software
CN = hub_proxy
[req_ext]
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = hub_proxy
IP.1 = ::1
IP.2 = 127.0.0.1
```

Notice the CN = hub_proxy and the DNS.1 = hub_proxy
I am not sure which solved this but when I regenerated the certificates and keys with these settings.

And then connected to the server using the hostname (in the client) of hub_proxy:9000 (where 9000 is the port number) it worked.